# AngularJS: Dynamic Injection of third party modules

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, dependencies, code-injection, ng-grid

Is there any way I can inject thirdparty modules dynamically, after angular bootstraping is done? I am trying with ngGrid and ngTable, but it doesnt work.

For example, I have defined my ngApp module:
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]); // 'app' i have defined in html like:
 ....

now on the fly i load controller.js, ng-grid.debug.js file and grid.html file :

grid.html contains:

controller.js contains $scope variable "gridOptions" for table data.

so i included ng-grid.debug.js on fly, but how to include "ngGrid" module on the fly, into main application module.

But things doesnt work. Can somebody please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I have added plunker also.. please check:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fFDQwX

so if i add 'ngGrid' in app.js file, in app module, it works file, but if i am doing same from demand.js on the fly, it wont work.